# How do you migrate specific Community pages from one sandbox to another?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, lightning-community, change-set, community-builder

We can deploy community pages according to https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_migrating_from_sandbox.htm

Is there a way to deploy few pages without deploying all pages. e.g. specify community builder created specific page names?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting - ExperienceBundleMetadata API.

You can enable with -
Setup > Communities Setting > Check EnableExperienceBundleMetadata API.

If you enable the same, you can deploy communities from one sandbox to another sandbox with -
Workbench
ANT
SFDX CLI (with mdapi commands).

Folder/metadata element is -

1. ExperienceBundle
2. ContentAsset
3. NavigationMenu
4. SiteDotCom
5. Network

Comment: Hi @YsrShk Thanks, But can we migrate single community page using this approach? It's easy to configure them in other instance, but error prone I guess when you have many changes/configs on community builder page. Since multiple devs are working on community, don't want to migrate all pages as a bundle too.

Comment: @PasanEeriyagama - bundle is nothing but a folder and some JSONs as a configuration. So you can simply add a new page/file and deploy it. Without taking other changes. so while deploying it look like bundle but in actual scenario its just target org bundle+new file/page.